# How to merge two datasets, based on key value in R

Tags: r, merge, key

I have two datasets, containing information on Airbnb listings, based on those listings' IDs. The first dataset, "calendar", includes for every ID and every date for 365 days ahead, the price and the availability of the listing. It has 4159641 rows and 4 columns.
The second data set, "Listings", includes for those same IDs several characteristics, like longitude, latitude, capacity, etc. It has 8903 rows and 9 variables.

Based on those common IDs I would like to combine the two datasets, so that all the information of the second data set "Listings" will be included to the first on "calendar". More precisely for every row of x listing data and price I want to include the information about longitude, latitude, capacity, etc. The dataset would then have 4159641 rows and 12 columns.

I would be really grateful to anyone who helps me with that.

Thank you!

[calendar dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzFZt.png)[Listing dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyleF.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about providing a minimally reproducible example, instead of images of your dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a left join since you want as many rows as there are observations in `df1`. Many ways to do that:

## Base R

This also works with a `data.table` object (`merge` is extended for this class of objects)

```r
merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE, by = 'ID)
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = 'ID')
```

I advice you to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) where you can find discussions on other types of join (inner, right...)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
calendar <- read.csv2(...)
listings <- read.csv2(...)

joined_data <- inner_join(calendar, listings, by="ID")
```

The gereral usage is, as follows:

```
join_type(first_data_set, second_data_set, by=column_to_join_on)
```

Be aware of the `join_type`:

- `inner_join`, will combine first and second tables based on the join-predicate
- `left_join`, will take all of the values from *first_data_set* and match them to records from *second_data_set*, in case of no matches `NULL` will appear
- `right_join`, is the opposite of `left_join`
- `...`,

There are more, you can check them by yourself in the package. But, the right one for you might be either `inner_join` or `left_join`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[dfd2, on = .(ID)]
```